# Access create new app from quick launch

Tags: quick-launch, excel-import

I'm trying to create a new link in the quick launch to access creating new import spreadsheet app instantly without going through clicking on Add app then searching for the app.

I tried using this link

```
{mysite}/_layouts/15/new.aspx?ListTemplate=SpreadsheetImport&ListBaseType=0&DisplayName=Spreadsheet+Import
```

but when I hit the import button after choosing the Excel sheet I get a pop up that an error has occurred and it never uploads the Excel file.

While the upload works fine if I go through the Add app route.

Can you please help with that I want the user to be able to access the new import spreadsheet instantly through quick launch without having to go through many options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited]

Try:

```
{mysite}/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//{Sitecollection}/{mysite}/_layouts/15/new.aspx?ListTemplate=SpreadsheetImport&ListBaseType=0&DisplayName=Spreadsheet+Import
```

This should redirect you to:

```
{mysite}/_layouts/15/new.aspx?ListTemplate=SpreadsheetImport&ListBaseType=0&DisplayName=Spreadsheet+Import
```

The process has an interim page that you need to hit on the way to the url you listed. Also previously I had removed a few arguments from the URL. That, it turns out, is another way to generate the errors you are experiencing. All 3 arguments are required for it to work.

Comment: same error. it didn't work can't import an error occurred

Comment: Updated the answer with new method that passes unit testing...